# angular5 JSON from response body

Tags: json, ionic-framework, httpclient, angular5

I got some trouble to add my data from get response into my data array.
I just read that you do not have to call .json now ( it not even compile ) because json is now part of angular httpClient.

But then, how do you put the date of the request into an array to be use with *ngFor... or is there another easier way of looping data into html...

I got my service:

```
return this.http.get(this.url).do((res : Response) => res);
```

then in my module:

```
dataArray = [];
///***///
this.getdata.getData().subscribe(data => this.dataArray = data);
```

how do I convert the type response: data to the array type ?

[EDIT]: Ok, I made some progress. Following @Azzi advice, I have to cast my data. And I found this tutorial that do want I want to do:

[angular example - http](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xogqdvrardj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.html)

In that I also found that I should make an interface that reflect my data model.
That in made in : pages/home/channel.ts

I been able to compile request and get method but my array still keep undefine.

here the git of the project: [arduino-thermostat](https://github.com/NitrofMtl/underdev-arduino-thermostat)

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will be getting an array, you can cast it like this

```
dataArray = [];
///***///
this.getdata.getData().subscribe(data => this.dataArray = <any[]> data);
```

here, data would be of type `any` which you probably want to cast using the `<>` to an array of any type

Answer (score 0):

Update your service to map the result returned into an Array:

```
return this.http.get<Array<any>>(this.url);
```

Declare an array in your module to store your data and instantiate it:

```
dataArray: Array<any> = [];
```

Then subscribe to the service in your module, the mapping will be done for you:

```
this.getData().subscribe(data => {
                this.dataArray = data;
            })
```